# Price in Google results showing wrong currency

Tags: google-search, microdata

I've noticed that our products in Google search results are showing in USD, despite the fact that our website is in GBP, our microdata is in GBP and our Merchant Centre is setup in GBP. I can't work out why we're seeing USD prices in search results:

[image: search result]

The following shows the results of the Google Rich Results test for the same page:

[image: rich results]

Are there any suggestions why google may be showing this in USD?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your shop seems to react on the requestor's IP address. When this is a US address, it shows the $ price. How to change that? In your script that serves the website, one of the first steps must be a reverse IP lookup of the IP from where the requests comes. Then parse the result for "Google". If it is Google, change the parameters of your site to the country settings that you want to see in Google. In all other cases, do nothing. This is not considered spoofing/fraud by Google, it will simply deliver the correct local settings to the searche engine, just the same that a real buyer from your country would see.